# ajax mysql search doesn't display the proper results

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to display the records based on user `combobox` search inputs. This `ajax` coding works fine. I have a small problem with this coding. For example I'm selecting 2014 from year. It will show all cars released in 2014. Then I'm selecting India from country. Now it should show all cars released in 2014 and Made in India. But it displays all cars released in 2014 and all cars made in india.

Because of this line on my `query` `( b.officially_released_year = '".$pass_year."' OR b.country_of_origin = '".$pass_country."' OR b.bodystyle = '".$pass_bodystyle."')` . I have changed OR to AND. But it doesn't display 2014 cars if I'm selecting 2014 from year combobox input. How do change this query if I want to proper results from database?

**ajax code**

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#search_year, #search_country, #search_bodystyle').on('change', function(){
            var year = $('#search_year').val();
            var country = $('#search_country').val();
            var bodystyle = $('#search_bodystyle').val();
            if(year || country || bodystyle){
                $('#loader').show();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?=get_url($topic, CAR_FINDER_SEARCH)?>",  //or your php page
                    data: { year: year, country: country, bodystyle: bodystyle }
                    })
                    .done(function(response) {
                        $('#car_finder_results').html(response);
                        $('#loader').hide();
                });
            }
        });
    });
 </script>
```

**php page**

```
<?php
        $pass_year = $_POST['year'];
        $pass_country = $_POST['country'];
        $pass_bodystyle = $_POST['bodystyle'];
        $sql_search = "SELECT b.model_name, b.maker_url, b.model_url FROM ".TBL_CAR_ADD_MODELS." a, ".TBL_CAR_SPEC_GENERAL." b WHERE a.model_id = b.model_id AND a.model_status = '1' AND ( b.officially_released_year = '".$pass_year."' OR b.country_of_origin = '".$pass_country."' OR b.bodystyle = '".$pass_bodystyle."')";
        $result = mysql_query($sql_search, $CN);
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
        while($get_search = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
    ?>
        <div class="all_list_imgs_anc" style="display:inline-block;">
            <a href="<?=asort_get_url(CAR_MAKE, $get_search['maker_url'], $get_search['model_url'])?>" class="img_anc_list">
                <span class="model_names"><?=$get_search['model_name'];?></span>
                <img src="<?=fa_model_image_path("medium", $get_search['maker_url'],$get_search['model_url'])?>" width="200" height="190" alt="<?=$get_search['model_name'];?>">
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php
        }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<div style='margin-top: 25px; text-align: center; width: 900px; display: inline-block;'>No Car Models</div>";
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $pass_year = $_POST['year'];
    $pass_country = $_POST['country'];
    $pass_bodystyle = $_POST['bodystyle'];

    if($pass_country=='')
    {
        $sql_search = "SELECT b.model_name, b.maker_url, b.model_url FROM ".TBL_CAR_ADD_MODELS." a, ".TBL_CAR_SPEC_GENERAL." b WHERE a.model_id = b.model_id AND a.model_status = '1' AND  b.officially_released_year = '".$pass_year."' OR b.country_of_origin = '".$pass_country."' AND b.bodystyle = '".$pass_bodystyle."'";
    }
    else
     $sql_search = "SELECT b.model_name, b.maker_url, b.model_url FROM ".TBL_CAR_ADD_MODELS." a, ".TBL_CAR_SPEC_GENERAL." b WHERE a.model_id = b.model_id AND a.model_status = '1' AND  b.officially_released_year = '".$pass_year."' AND b.country_of_origin = '".$pass_country."' AND b.bodystyle = '".$pass_bodystyle."'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql_search, $CN);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
    while($get_search = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
?>
    <div class="all_list_imgs_anc" style="display:inline-block;">
        <a href="<?=asort_get_url(CAR_MAKE, $get_search['maker_url'], $get_search['model_url'])?>" class="img_anc_list">
            <span class="model_names"><?=$get_search['model_name'];?></span>
            <img src="<?=fa_model_image_path("medium", $get_search['maker_url'],$get_search['model_url'])?>" width="200" height="190" alt="<?=$get_search['model_name'];?>">
        </a>
    </div>
<?php
    }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<div style='margin-top: 25px; text-align: center; width: 900px; display: inline-block;'>No Car Models</div>";
    }
?>
```